# .NET Core 1.1 build and class recognition bug on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have recently started developing a test project on the latest **.NET Core version 1.1** and I have been experiencing considerable amount of issues though most of them could be solved by browsing the web. I am currently using **Visual Studio 2017 community**.

There is one particular annoying bug which involves the following (some steps to reproduce it):

- Use the command line interface and execute the **dotnet build** command at least once to build the project.
- Open the solution and create a new class in a random folder in the solution.
- Once the class is created I notice that there is no **triangle-dropdown option** for the new class. It seems that for some reason the solution does not recognize the class that I just created and it cannot be referenced by other classes in the same solution. All classes are **public** etc. so it is not a coding problem. I also checked the **build options** and there are no differences between the problematic class and other classes in the solution.
- Then what I need to do is close the solution, execute the **dotnet build** command once again and then reopen the solution using the **File > Open** menu in Visual Studio. Notice that if you reopen the solution from the **Recent** list it will **NOT** work and the class will still be unrecognized in the project structure.

I have to say that sometimes for unknown reasons even if I follow properly all the mentioned steps above the trick is not going to work and I have to reopen and build several times. There was a similar project build issue on **.NET Core 1.0** as well (proper building only works by using the **CLI**).

One issue I also notice in the 1.1 version is that after you create a new folder anywhere in the solution this folder will not appear in the **.csproject** file (in the **ItemGroup** xml tag) which also should not happen. Basically it seems that the **.csproj** file is not reflecting any changes done to the solution.

Could all of that be a caching issue ?

So far the .NET Core technology has been really impressive to me clearly showing a brighter future for developers however I have been experiencing enormous amount of troubleshooting issues especially in the latest 1.1 version.

Regards,
R.F.

Comment: Do you have the proper tools installed and made sure to uninstall older versions of the .NET Core SDK? Check Control Panel > Programs & Features if you have any of the older SDKs (ones labeled preview), also in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk` and see if there are any previews (if yes, they should also appear in programs & features). Latest SDK on my PC is ".NET Core SDK 1.0.3 (x64)" installed with the yesterdays VS2017 update

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though I found the source of the issue to be something different.

Comment: Don't post the answer as update inside the question. Please remove it and post it as a proper answer and mark it as correct once the grace period is over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found:**

I managed to find the source of the issue. It seems that in **Visual Studio 2017** a new option has been implemented called **Lightweight solution load** and this option is causing the issue of not recognizing new classes and references. Once I switched it off it worked as intended. The **Lightweight Solution Load** option button appears next to the **Open Folder in File Explorer** and you might accidentally click it.